# Intersecting multiple columns between two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames with 2 columns in each. For example:

```
df.1 = data.frame(col.1 = c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","d"), col.2 = c("b","c","d","e","c","d","e","d","e","e"))
df.2 = data.frame(col.1 = c("b","b","b","a","a","e"), col.2 = c("a","c","e","c","e","c"))
```

and I'm looking for an efficient way to look up the row index in df.2 of every col.1 col.2 row pair of df.1. Note that a row pair in df.1 may appear in df.2 in reverse order (for example df.1[1,], which is "a","b" appears in df.2[1,] as "b","a"). That doesn't matter to me. In other words, as long as a row pair in df.1 appears in any order in df.2 I want its row index in df.2, otherwise it should return NA. One more note, row pairs in both data frames are unique - meaning each row pair appears only once.

So for these two data frames the return vector would be:

```
c(1,4,NA,5,2,NA,3,NA,6,NA)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something using `dplyr` package:

### first make the reference frame

- use `row_number()` to number as per row index efficiently.
- use `select` to "flip" the column vars.

two halves:

```
df_ref_top <- df.2 %>% mutate(n=row_number())
df_ref_btm <- df.2 %>% select(col.1=col.2, col.2=col.1) %>% mutate(n=row_number())
```

then bind together:

```
df_ref <- rbind(df_ref_top,df_ref_btm)
```

### Left join and select vector:

gives to get your answer

```
left_join(df.1,df_ref)$n
```

Comment: Since `dplyr` is screaming fast, I timed your method against mine on a `df.1` with 5e5 rows and a `df.2` with 1e5 rows. `dplyr` took 0.3 sec, while the `match` and `apply` method took 74 sec. For large data frames, `dplyr` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Per @thelatemail's comment, here's a more elegant approach: 
match(apply(df.1,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="")),
      apply(df.2,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="")))

# My original answer, for reference:
# Check for matches with both orderings of df.2's columns
match.tmp = cbind(match(paste(df.1[,1],df.1[,2]), paste(df.2[,1],df.2[,2])),
                  match(paste(df.1[,1],df.1[,2]), paste(df.2[,2],df.2[,1])))

# Convert to single vector of match indices
match.index = apply(match.tmp, 1, 
                    function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, max(x, na.rm=TRUE)))

 [1]  1  4 NA  5  2 NA  3 NA  6 NA
```

Comment: I like the principle but you could probably simplify it a touch to: `match(apply(df.1,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="")),apply(df.2,1,function(x) paste(sort(x),collapse="")))`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little function that tests a few of the looping options in R (which was not really intentional, but it happened).

```
check.rows <- function(data1, data2)
{
  df1 <- as.matrix(data1);df2 <- as.matrix(data2);ll <- vector('list', nrow(df1))
  for(i in seq(nrow(df1))){
    ll[[i]] <- sapply(seq(nrow(df2)), function(j) df2[j,] %in% df1[i,])
  }
  h <- sapply(ll, function(x) which(apply(x, 2, all)))
  sapply(h, function(x) ifelse(is.double(x), NA, x))
}

check.rows(df.1, df.2)
## [1]  1  4 NA  5  2 NA  3 NA  6 NA
```

And here's a benchmark when row dimensions are increased for both `df.1` and `df.2`.  Not too bad I guess, considering the 24 checks on each of 40 rows.

```
> dim(df.11); dim(df.22)
[1] 40  2
[1] 24  2
> f <- function() check.rows(df.11, df.22)
> microbenchmark(f())
## Unit: milliseconds
##  expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
##   f() 75.52258 75.94061 76.96523 78.61594 81.00019   100
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) sort/merge** First sort `df.2` creating `df.2.s` and append a row number column.  Then merge this new data frame with `df.1` (which is already sorted in the question):

```
df.2.s <- replace(df.2, TRUE, t(apply(df.2, 1, sort)))
df.2.s$row <- 1:nrow(df.2.s)
merge(df.1, df.2.s, all.x = TRUE)$row
```

The result is:

```
[1]  1  4 NA  5  2 NA  3 NA  6 NA
```

**2) sqldf** Since dot is an SQL operator rename the data frames as `df1` and `df2`.  Note that for the same reason the column names will be transformed to `col_1` and `col_2` when `df1` and `df2` are automatically uploaded to the backend database.  We sort `df2` using `min` and `max` and left join it to `df1` (which is already sorted):

```
df1 <- df.1
df2 <- df.2

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select b.rowid row
    from df1
    left join 
    (select min(col_1, col_2) col_1, max(col_1, col_2) col_2 from df2) b
    using (col_1, col_2)")$row
```

**REVISED** Some code improvements.  Added second solution.